# Microsoft Live Messenger only signs in when I have a Socks proxy

Tags: windows, proxy, login, windows-live-messenger

I've installed the last version of Microsoft Live Messenger. The problem I have is that it signs in to the server just if I start a Socks proxy. Otherwise, it can not signs me in, and tell me there is some errors regarding to **Key ports**. When I go to troubleshooting, the HTTP test is successful. But TCP test returns fail status when I did not run my Socks Proxy.
What's the problem ? I always get error "**80072eff**".

Comment: Tell us about your network connection and why you have a proxy

Comment: I use Proxifier to access some website that are filtered for me. Everything is very normal. A wireless network with an ADSL internet connection

Comment: Couldn't it just be that this is also filtered?

Comment: No it is not Paul

Comment: So you have a very normal ADSL connection, except some sites are filtered, yet you are certain this one is not, yet it doesn't work unless you bypass the filter?  I suggest you contact your ISP.

Comment: Thank you Paul for the time you spent on my problem. I will do it ...